# Modifying manually pytorch state_dict file and retrain

Tags: pytorch

I save and load pytorch state_dict file and then evaluate and retrain the model. That works.

```
torch.save(net.state_dict(), path)
net.load_state_dict(torch.load(path))
```

However, when I modify the `state_dict` file (manually changing the values) after loading it and evaluating it, I receive the error:

```
RuntimeError: a leaf Variable that requires grad has been used in an in-place operation.
```

How to safely modify the `state_dict` and then retrain it without the error?

Comment: please give a minimal code example of the way you modify the `state_dict`.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49316176/1714410) might answer your question